# How to create Summation SUM() with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, sum, record

i have record like this :

```
-----------------------------
| number  |  name  | price  |
|---------------------------|
|  1      |  Aaaa  | 20     |
|  2      |  Bbb   | 30     |
-----------------------------
|            amount| 50     |
-----------------------------
```

here's my code :

```
<?php $i=0; ?>
@foreach ($buckets as $b)
<tr>
    <td>{{$no++}}</td>
    <td>{{$b->name}}</td>
    <td>Rp <span class="harga[{{$i}}]">{{$b->harga}}</span></td>
    <td>Hapus</td>
</tr>
<?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
<tr>
        <td colspan="5">amount</td>
        <td colspan="2"><span class="amount"></span></td>
</tr>
```

I do not want to use sql function (SUM()) for summation, but I want to sum them by using JQUERY. Can you tell me how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

here is sample using jquery hope it will help.

```
<table id="mytable">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Aaaa</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Bbbb</td>
        <td>30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Amount</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
total = 0;
$("#mytable tr").not(":last").each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  var value = parseInt($this.find('td:last').html(),10);
  total = total+value;
});
//use total here 
console.log(total);
```